# How do I complete a sideways encounter?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

In Fortnite, we’re currently in chapter 2 season 8 and I’m stuck on a mission for Torin to complete a sideways encounter:

[image: Screenshot of the mission.]

According to [my research](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/fortnite-sideways-encounter-complete-encounter-anomaly-locations-8006), to complete a sideways encounter I need to defeat three waves of cube monsters within a set time limit that begins when I enter the sideways:

> Sideways encounters in Fortnite involve fighting off waves of Cube Monsters until you fill the orange challenge bar at the top of your screen. If you do this successfully, then you will complete the Sideways encounter. There is, however, a catch and it comes in the form of a timer.

Upon entering the sideways, a bar is supposed to appear at the top of the screen:

[image: Screenshot of the aforementioned bar.]

However, I’ve dedicated almost 30 matches solely to accomplishing this mission and have not once seen the bar. I have however noticed three circles at the top (I’ll try to get a screenshot soon) that appears when (as I know them) the cube bosses do:

[image: Screenshot of all three bosses.]

However, defeating them (which is a pain alone by the way), doesn’t complete the encounter, so I’m missing *something*.

---

How do I complete a sideways encounter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, I've been going to the wrong location this whole time. A sideways encounter isn't the large bubble on the map when jumping from the battle bus:

[image: Screenshot of the large sideways bubble.]

Instead, it's marked on the map with a little glowing purple area:

[image: Screenshot of the map area.]

When you encounter it on the ground, it looks like an orb of glowing purple light:

[image: Screenshot of the orb on the ground.]

Walk up to it to begin the encounter, then kill everything inside the bubble that forms, until it tells you you're done.

Comment: Just incase you're unaware, you can accept your own answer.

Comment: @n00dles not for another 6 hours :)

Comment: Ah ok. Didn't know there was a timer :)